# How to find the same characters in a string and display them as a quantity

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to display each of the characters with their quantity

Input Specification
The first line of input contains the number N, which is the number of lines that follow. The next
N lines will contain at least one and at most 80 characters, none of which are spaces.

Output Specification
Output will be N lines. Line i of the output will be the encoding of the line i + 1 of the input.
The encoding of a line will be a sequence of pairs, separated by a space, where each pair is an
integer (representing the number of times the character appears consecutively) followed by a space,
followed by the character.

**Sample Input**

```
4
+++===!!!!
777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT
(AABBC)
3.1415555
```

**Output for Sample Input**

```
3 + 3 = 4 !
6 7 6 . 12 T
1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 )
1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. However, I suspect that `Counter` from the the `collections` module will ease your journey.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: isn't the first line `1 4` BTW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `itertools.groupby` and format the result: value and length of the group. Join the elements:

```
import itertools

s = "+++===!!!! 777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT (AABBC) 3.1415555"

result = "".join(["{} {}".format(sum(1 for _ in group),value) for value,group in itertools.groupby(s)])
```

result:

```
3 + 3 = 4 ! 1   6 7 6 . 12 T 1   1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 ) 1   1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

without a key parameter, `itertools.groupby` just groups identical items into groups, preserving the order. Just count them. Here I chose to *not* create a list to consume the group (`len(list(group))`) but just do `sum(1 for _ in group)`

Comment: How do I modify this so it will change depending on different strings/inputs?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
s = "+++===!!!! 777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT (AABBC) 3.1415555"
d = {char: 0 for char in s}
for char in s:
    d[char] += 1

output = "".join([" {} {}".format(value, key) for key, value in d.items()])
# outputs: '3 + 3 = 4 ! 3 6 7 7 . 1 2 T 1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 ) 1 3 2 1 1 4 4 5'
```

Comment: @revliscano You can use `collection.Counter` instead of building the dict `d`. +1

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks, I really appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you aren't looking for total repeating characters, I would suggest reading the string backward and for each character, you want to count how many times it appears as you're iterating through, and once you hit a different character you use the current count for the output. In fact, you could generate your output as you iterate through the string backward.

It might look something like this:

```
reverse = input[-1:0]
output = ''
count = 0
letter = reverse[0]

for k in range(0, len(reverse)):
    if reverse[k] == letter and k != len(reverse) - 1:
        count += 1
    else:
        output = str(count) + ' ' + reverse[k] + ' ' + output
        letter = reverse[k]
        count = 0
```